# how to handle ember data error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to follow the guide here which is just active last 3 months - https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945

So i had my code like this:

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend
    beforeModel: (transition) ->
        alert('before')

    model: ->      
      App.User.find({}).then (response) ->     
        # my code here parses response and sets it 
        self.controllerFor('users').set('content', response.users)   

      # for some reason i need to at least return an array
      []

    events:
      error: (error, transition) ->   
        alert(error.message)
```

But the error callback under events is never triggerd. I force my server to return a 500 server error.

beforeModel (or afterModel) isn't triggered as well.

Answer (score 3):

Example of how I would do this using the latest builds of Ember and EmberData:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.User = DS.Model;

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(){
    alert('before');
  },

  model: function() {
    this.store.find('user', {}).then(function() {
      alert('response');
    }, function() {
      alert('error');
    });
  }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1193/edit?html,js,output)

Errors can be handled in the second (`reject`) callback of the promise (`then`).

Comment: Hi, you are not returning this.store.find here. How will your model get assigned to the response?

Comment: @user2745266 I probably just forgot the `return` because I'm used to CoffeeScript, but you could potentially assign something in the success callback and just return nothing for this controller's model (as is done in the question).